# How can I override admin column name 'is_staff' and 'is_superuser' in django?

Tags: python, django

[image: Screenshot of Django Admin]

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):

    """ Custom User Model """
    
    ..........
    #Custom stuff
    ..........
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from . import models
    
    
@admin.register(models.User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

   """ Custom User Admin """
   
   ........
   #Custom Stuff
   ........

   list_display = (
        "username",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "is_active",
        "language",
        "currency",
        "superhost",
        "is_staff",
        "is_superuser",
        "email_verified",
        "login_method",
    )

    def is_staff(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

    is_staff.short_description = "Staff"

    def is_superuser(self, obj):
        return obj.is_superuser

    is_superuser.short_description = "Superuser"
```

I've wrote the code above to override the coulmn name of 'is_staff' and 'is_superuser', which is 'STAFF STATUS' and 'SUPERUSER STATUS', to 'STAFF' and 'SUPERUSER'. But it doesn't working. What should I do to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the properties the same as the field name, so it [ignores your definition](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L319).

Use a different name, like below to fix it.

```py
@admin.register(models.User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

   """ Custom User Admin """
   
   ........
   #Custom Stuff
   ........

   list_display = (
        "username",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "is_active",
        "language",
        "currency",
        "superhost",
        "staff",
        "superuser",
        "email_verified",
        "login_method",
    )

    def staff(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

    staff.short_description = "Staff"

    def superuser(self, obj):
        return obj.is_superuser

    superuser.short_description = "Superuser"
```

Comment: Your way just fixed that problem!! Thx so much for your answer :)